# Boost Graph layout algorithmes (Fruchterman-Reingold)

Tags: c++, boost, graph-layout

I have a big problem with using boost layouts. I'm using directed graph and Fruchterman-Reingold layout algorithm. The topology I use is rectangle topology. I have to organize around 200 elements on my scene (I'm using QT scene and items to do it). Boost library is used only to calculate position of elements. My items are rectangles with different size, but we can say it's constant to simplify. Everything works pretty well, except that some of my items sometimes lay on each other. I tried to change, both, attraction and repulsive force but it's still doesn't work at all.

My question is there any way to push away elements from each other. I found something called jitter points in Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm, but changing it didn't help me. Maybe there is way to use rectangle size instead of point (topology<>::point_type) but i can't find it?

Thanks for every idea and help.